# Import six module not working despite pip installation

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-oauth, six

I am building a web app (based on google app engine & python 2.7) and trying to import the six.move module. But although "six" is installed, it is not found when importing (note, I am not using frameworks yet like Django).

On my working environment (env), I ran:

```
| => pip show six
Name: six

Version: 1.11.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /path/to/file/DeployedProjects/goinpact/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

The module that calls for this package is "id_token.py" from "google.oauth2"

So, when I run

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
```

and then load my web app, the import error log reads:

```
File "/path/to/file/DeployedProjects/goinpact/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 19, in <module>
from six.moves import http_client
ImportError: No module named six.moves
```

The id_token.py module calls:

```
from six.moves import http_client
```

...causing the log import error above.

My understanding is that if on my environment (env), I can see that "six" is installed, I should have no problem importing this module from my app. Is this somehow not correct?

I must be missing something basic but can't understand what? Please help!

PS: Resources I have also attempted:

A)
Even calling from my "main.py" file:

```
import six
```

results in the same ImportError.

B)
[ImportError: No module named six](http://Hello,%20%20%20I%20am%20building%20a%20web%20app%20(based%20on%20google%20app%20engine%20&%20python%202.7)%20and%20trying%20to%20import%20the%20six.move%20module.%20But%20although%20%22six%22%20is%20installed,%20it%20is%20not%20found%20when%20importing.%20%20%20On%20my%20working%20environment%20(env),%20I%20ran:%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%20=%3E%20pip%20show%20six%20%20%20%20%20Name:%20six%20%20%20%20%20%20Version:%201.11.0%20%20%20%20%20Summary:%20Python%202%20and%203%20compatibility%20utilities%20%20%20%20%20Home-page:%20http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/%20%20%20%20%20Author:%20Benjamin%20Peterson%20%20%20%20%20Author-email:%20benjamin@python.org%20%20%20%20%20License:%20MIT%20%20%20%20%20Location:%20/path/to/file/DeployedProjects/goinpact/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages%20%20%20%20%20Requires:%20%20%20%20The%20module%20that%20calls%20for%20this%20package%20is%20%22id_token.py%22%20from%20%22google.oauth2%22%20%20So,%20when%20I%20run%20%20%20%20%20%20%20from%20google.oauth2%20import%20id_token%20%20%20and%20then%20load%20my%20web%20app,%20the%20import%20error%20log%20reads:%20%20%20%20%20%20File%20%22/path/to/file/DeployedProjects/goinpact/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/id_token.py%22,%20line%2019,%20in%20%3Cmodule%3E%20%20%20%20%20from%20six.moves%20import%20http_client%20%20%20%20%20ImportError:%20No%20module%20named%20six.moves%20%20%20The%20id_token.py%20module%20calls:%20%20%20%20%20%20from%20six.moves%20import%20http_client%20%20...causing%20the%20log%20import%20error%20above.%20%20%20My%20understanding%20is%20that%20if%20on%20my%20environment%20(env),%20I%20can%20see%20that%20%22six%22%20is%20installed,%20I%20should%20have%20no%20problem%20importing%20this%20module%20from%20my%20app.%20Is%20this%20somehow%20not%20correct?%20%20%20I%20must%20be%20missing%20something%20silly,%20but%20can't%20figure%20this%20out,%20please%20help!%20%20%20Resources%20I%20have%20also%20attempted%20from%20this%20site:%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967428/importerror-no-module-named-six)

C) Unresolved:
[Cannot install python six module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853692/cannot-install-python-six-module)

Comment: I'd check whether the packages in lib are installing their own (possibly old) versions of `six`, then maybe specify the version you want in your vendor requirements file and reinstall your vendor packages.

Comment: If this is a standard env app try using the GAE-provided `six` lib by requesting it in the `libraries` section of your `app.yaml` file. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime

Comment: Here's how I resolved this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51616840/901444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Python virtual environment is activated, paths are rewritten to add `{env}/lib/python2.7/`. However, GAE isn't itself aware of virtual environments. So if you want `six` (or some other pure-Python library) to be available to your app, you'll need to arrange that yourself. Instructions on how to do this are in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27